# How to move my parallax background image under the header div

Tags: html, css

My parallax background image goes under my div I want to use as a header.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div id="header" class="text-center">
    <img src="media/logo.png">
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div id="content" class="jumbotron text-center">
    <!-- Content here  -->
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>
```

And here the CSS rules related to it:

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    background-image: url("../media/Collage1.png
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 50%; 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You don't see your header, because your .parallax overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/12/54/world-map-146505_960_720.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" class="text-center">
    <!-- <img src="media/logo.png"> -->
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div id="content" class="jumbotron text-center">
    <!-- Content here  -->
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used position: fixed in #header also gave width: 100%; You can also use position: absolute;

Comment: You're most welcome. If you think the answer is a good technical one then kindly approve or vote it up so that people can get benefit from your question 

Answer (score 0):

Change the height from `50%` to `50px` (or as per your need)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>


</header>
<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px;padding:20px;color:white;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="parallax-2"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;background-color:blue;font-size:36px;padding:20px;color:white;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```